# sometimes on saving a post as draft, it says Access Denied You don't have permission to access "mywebsite.com/wp-admin/post.php"

Tags: posts, htaccess, accessibility

It only occurs sometimes, when i try to save a post as a draft, with a content having anchor target="_blank", it throws an error on saving `Access Denied`

[image]

I set up it locally and its working fine.

I tried below code, but didnt worked.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:php)$">
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: "It only occurs sometimes" - so, it is OK and saves successfully when you try it again later, with no other changes? Incidentally, the code you say you've "tried" above, would actually _cause_ this problem, not fix it?!

Comment: i was facing the issue, before the above code, and the same even after the above code. and once it started showing access denied i have to wait long, to save it again. but wanted to fix the issue.